# location of cassandra.port in BAM2.2.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam, wso2-esb

I would like to monitor my application server application using WSO2 BAM. Intially I 
didn't change the BAM offset address, keep it as by default(ie offset 0) and I changed the 
application server offset as 2. It seems some problem to show. If I change the offset of BAM 
server as 2. How can I change the cassandra.port address. I mean the location of the file in BAM 2.2.0 server.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra port can be changed from wso2bam-2.2.0/repository/conf/etc/cassandra-component.xml.

But if you change BAM offset to 2, it automatically increases Cassandra port as well, unless you have enabled

```
<!--Nodes>localhost:9160</Nodes-->
```

entry in cassandra-component.xml.

Answer (score 0):

If Lakmali's answer is not working properly apply the port offsets in,

1. All Hive scripts, if port numbers are used inside them. (Make sure you use DROP TABLE command before each Hive table's CREATE command, if you update the script in the same BAM pack without extracting a fresh pack.)
2. Cassandra port numbers in wso2bam-2.2.0/repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml file.