# WSO2 BAM wirh offset 1. Cassandra error

Tags: cassandra, wso2, wso2-bam

i have a problem on startup of BAM server.
My machine has the IP 1.33.33.127 and hostname "srv-lc-presen".

I it have  configurated using this document:
[Monitoring and statistics](https://docs.wso2.org/display/AM131/Monitoring+and+Statistics).

I have modified the  at carbon.xml. I  have it set to 1.

I've modified the master-datasources.xml and set 
`WSO2BAM_CASSANDRA_DATASOURCE url = jdbc:cassandra://srv-lc-presen:9161/EVENT_KS
WSO2BAM_UTIL_DATASOURCE url = jdbc:cassandra://srv-lc-presen:9161/BAM_UTIL_KS`

I have tried with localhost, 1.33.33.127 and srv-lc-presen.
I always get the same error:

```
 ERROR {me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager} -  Could not start connection pool for host srv-lc-presen(1.33.33.127):9161
[2014-05-07 12:04:24,983]  WARN {me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.CassandraHostRetryService} -  Downed srv-lc-presen(1.33.33.127):9161 host still appears to be down: Unable to open transport to srv-lc-presen(1.33.33.127):9161 , java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
[2014-05-07 12:04:24,987] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.bam.notification.task.internal.NotificationDispatchComponent} -  All host pools marked down. Retry burden pushed out to client.
me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HectorException: All host pools marked down. Retry burden pushed out to client.
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.getClientFromLBPolicy(HConnectionManager.java:393)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.operateWithFailover(HConnectionManager.java:249)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ThriftCluster.addKeyspace(ThriftCluster.java:168)
        at org.wso2.carbon.bam.datasource.utils.DataSourceUtils.createKeyspaceIfNotExist(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
        at org.wso2.carbon.bam.datasource.utils.DataSourceUtils.getClusterKeyspaceFromRDBMSConfig(DataSourceUtils.java:92)
        at org.wso2.carbon.bam.datasource.utils.DataSourceUtils.getClusterKeyspaceFromRDBMSDataSource(DataSourceUtils.java:96)
```

---

**NEW information**

i have tried to reconfigure and i don't find the problem.
I see in BAM console this error

```
[2014-05-08 09:10:57,531] ERROR {me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager} -  Could not start connection pool for host 1.33.33.127(1.33.33.127):9161
[2014-05-08 09:10:57,564] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.bam.notification.task.internal.NotificationDispatchComponent} -  All host pools marked down. Retry burden pushed out to client.
me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HectorException: All host pools marked down. Retry burden pushed out to client.
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.getClientFromLBPolicy(HConnectionManager.java:393)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.operateWithFailover(HConnectionManager.java:249)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ThriftCluster.addKeyspace(ThriftCluster.java:168)
        at org.wso2.carbon.bam.datasource.utils.DataSourceUtils.createKeyspaceIfNotExist(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
        at org.wso2.carbon.bam.datasource.utils.DataSourceUtils.getClusterKeyspaceFromRDBMSConfig(DataSourceUtils.java:92)
        at org.wso2.carbon.bam.datasource.utils.DataSourceUtils.getClusterKeyspaceFromRDBMSDataSource(DataSourceUtils.java:96)
        at org.wso2.carbon.bam.notification.task.internal.NotificationDispatchComponent.initRecordStore(NotificationDispatchComponent.java:72)
        at org.wso2.carbon.bam.notification.task.internal.NotificationDispatchComponent.activate(NotificationDispatchComponent.java:64)
```

And in API Manager console this

```
[2014-05-08 09:14:52,096] ERROR - ReceiverGroup No receiver is reachable at reconnection, can't publish the events
[2014-05-08 09:14:55,102] ERROR - AsyncDataPublisher Reconnection failed for for tcp://1.33.33.127:7612/
```

Comment: hope following will help to solve your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675295/location-of-cassandra-port-in-bam2-2-0

Comment: I don't find the problem.
I updated the post with more information.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please use this command at startup or edit wso2server.sh if you are not using notification feature **sh wso2server.sh -Ddisable.notification.task**

https://docs.wso2.org/display/BAM240/Notifications